# Problems with Socketlabs library on Linux systems

Tags: python

I am running an script on windows pc, and it is working pretty nice. But, when i try to move the script on linux-based system, i keep getting errors from one of the libraries, which is called Socketlabs-injectionapi.

Firstly, when i tried to install the library using `pip install`, i was getting an error for bad encoding in the setup. I've fixed that by just removing the `encoding='utf-8'` from the setup, and installing it again from the edited file.

After the installation was successfull, i tried to run the script. But now i am getting other strange error:

```
lab@ubuntu:~/Desktop/chromeless $ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from socketlabs.injectionapi.message.basicmessage import BasicMessage
  File "/home/lab/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/socketlabs/injectionapi/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .socketlabsclient import SocketLabsClient
  File "/home/lab/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/socketlabs/injectionapi/socketlabsclient.py", line 21
    def __init__(self, server_id: int, api_key: str, proxy: Proxy = None):
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please, keep in mind that the exactly same code is working on windows, without any problems. Any suggestions what is causing that errors? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using python 2 try to run with python3

Comment: Hey @geckos . After upgrading all libraries to python3, and fixing again the encoding, it worked. Thank you !